# Can't get one div to show and the rest to hide using buttons

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show, show-hide

I have four buttons and I would like to be able to click them to see only their div and no others. I have seen a lot of solutions but they just don't seem to be working with buttons rather than links. I need the buttons for the fade affect (or at least, that's the only way I could make the fade work correctly...)
Here's my HTML. The parent class is just for formatting and below are my buttons. I want l1 to go to div1 and so one basically.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div id="div1" style="display:none;">About me content</div>
    <div id="div2" style="display:none;">About me content</div>
</div>
<div class="up">
<pre>
<a href="http://www.brynntweeddale.com/"><img src="http://www.brynntweeddale.com/images/logo.png" style="width: 123px; height: 60px; vertical-align: middle;" /></a><button id="l1" onclick="fade(this);">ABOUT</button><button id="l2" onclick="fade(this);">PHOTOGRAPHY</button><button id=" l3">DESIGN</button><button id="l4" onclick="fade(this);">CONTACT</button></pre>
</div>
```

I haven't been to get any script to work, but I assume I would use something like this:

```
  $('.parent  div').hide();

$('#nav a').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).index('a'));
    var $div = $('.parent > div').eq($(this).index('#nav a'));
    $div.show();
    $('.parent > div').not($div).hide();
});
```

But for buttons instead of links.

Overall, I think I'm just really confused.

Comment: *sidenote:* `<button>` without specifying type will be treated as form submit button. Why use `<pre>` to surround the navigation?

Comment: I need to fix the button names, but they usually have spaces around them that need to be taken into account. I've just fiddled around so much that they aren't there right now. I don't know much about buttons or types of buttons..could that fix my problem?

Comment: 1. You should make a JSFiddle; 2. You should remove `<pre>`; 3. You should add `type="button"` to all your buttons / don't use `<button>` tag (use CSS instead)

Comment: Well, if I remove pre, the spaces I need won't show up anymore. I don't understand what I'm changing the button to, but I guess I'll just play around with it more.

Comment: Use CSS to adjust visual spacing.  Where is your CSS ?

Comment: **fade**  is not defined, what framework are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if can help you, but this can be a starting point:

[image]

Note: I assume you are using `JQuery` and `Bootstrap`

**http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/ffwtro2e/**

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div id="div1" style="display:none;">DIV1 content</div>
    <div id="div2" style="display:none;">DIV2 content</div>
    <div id="div3" style="display:none;">DIV3 content</div>
    <div id="div4" style="display:none;">DIV4 content</div>
</div>
<div class="up">
<a href="http://www.brynntweeddale.com/"><img src="http://www.brynntweeddale.com/images/logo.png" style="width: 123px; height: 60px; vertical-align: middle;" /></a>

    <button id="l1" class='btn' >ABOUT</button>
    <button id="l2" class='btn' >PHOTOGRAPHY</button>
    <button id="l3" class='btn' >DESIGN</button>
    <button id="l4" class='btn' >CONTACT</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
    $('.parent  div').hide();

    $('.btn').on('click', function(){
        $('.parent  div').hide();
        var bid = $(this)[0].id[1];
        var sel = '#div' + bid;
        $(sel).fadeToggle();

    });
});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, super glitchy in IE, but I'll take it! Thanks.